# Is the escaping provided by the Google-Gson library enough to ensure a safe JSON payload?

Tags: java, javascript, security, json

I am currently using the Google-Gson library to convert Java objects into JSON inside a web service.

Once the object has been converted to JSON, it is returned to the client to be converted into a JSON object using the JavaScript eval() function. Is the character escaping provided by the Gson library enough to ensure that nothing nasty will happen when I run the eval() function on the JSON payload?

Do I need to HTML Encode the Strings in the Java Objects before passing them to the Gson library? Are there any other security concerns that I should be aware of?

Comment: just don't use eval, use JSON.parse (available in most modern browsers)

Comment: If I were to use JSON.parse, would HTML Encoding the object on the server side provide any value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Gson is not meant to be used to securely encode JSON in all possible cases. Instead, use a library dedicated to securely parse JSON. [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is a good example.

Comment: GSON does indeed encode anything I throw at it and even needs special calls to disable encoding things it doesn't have to, like HTML. That said, I voted this up because the correct answer is not to parse JSON on the receiver side with eval, but to use the linked method. So ++.